# How to combine request coming from two different application take data from one request and send it as a response to the other request?

Tags: javascript, https, server, client-server

I am working on a project for my class. the application facilitate users to upgrade their PCs. The application has three parts a react front-end, node.js server and a C# application(scanner) that the user downloads from the from-end and runs it locally in user's PC. After the scanner is ran, it extracts the existing hardware specs from the user's PC and send it as a json object to the server through a HTTP request. the server API takes this information and generates a compatible upgraded parts list from our database. I am struggling to find a way to return this API generated data to the react front-end opened on the user's end.

The API is a REST API

I am new to using node js and dealing with HTTP requests. It will be helpful if some one can provide any solution, documentation or article which I could be helpful to implement this functionality. also feel free to give any suggestions on how to achieve this connection between the three parts.

Here is the code where react front end that is sending the request for scanner.exe

```
  handleDownload = () =>{
    const scn_URL = "http://localhost:5000/fileApi?name=User_scanner.exe";
    Axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: scn_URL,
      responseType: 'blob'
    })
    .then(response =>{
      console.log(response.data);
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = url;
      link.setAttribute('download', 'scanner.exe');
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
    })

  }
```

here is the server side API code that is serving the scanner.exe file

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
    const fileName = req.query.name;
    const filepath = "C:\\Users\\Sakib_PC\\my files\\senior_Design\\Senior_DesignS19_group_5\\back-end-testing\\serverAPI\\public\\User_scanner.exe"
    console.log(`Got file name: ${fileName}`);
    res.set({'Content-Type':'application/octet-stream'})
    res.sendFile(filepath, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            next(err)
        } else {
            console.log('Sent:', fileName)
        }
    });

});

module.exports = router;
```

The scanner is sending the information as json to the server and named "data" in the code below

```
  private async void SendJson_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("send button was clicked");

            const string url = "http://localhost:5000/testApi";
            var data = new StringContent(this.jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            string response;

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage res = await client.PostAsync(url, data);

            response = res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            Console.WriteLine(response);
            if (response == "message recieved")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(response);
                this.finishButton.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("nothing ");
            }
        }
```

the code for API that catches this data is given below:

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

router.post("/", function (req, res, next) {
    const msg = req.body;
    console.log(msg);
    const modMsg = "message recieved";

    res.send( modMsg);
})

module.exports = router;
```

the data that is being received by the server from scanner is given in the link which is what is intended.
[image of the json data being send by the scanner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbfPX.png)
is there any way I can send the scanner data the api caught to the front end that made the download request in the first hand. Keeping in mind that the download GET request made from the website and POST request made from the scanner are two different request. My goal is to take the data from the scanner POST request and serve it to the client from where It made the Download request

thank you!

Comment: Could you please provide code of your api where you are receiving  http request then it would be easier for me to give answer

Comment: hey @Shohanur thanks for reaching out. I have added the code for the request the front-end makes to get the scanner and the code being executed on the API side that servers the scanner.exe file. the user will run this scanner.exe file on their PC and it will send the current hardware specs data as a json to the server this functionality  which have not been implemented yet. for now if we could present any data sent from the scanner on the front end website opened on the users end, would be a success.

Comment: Did you catch data from scanner  in API end?

Comment: Yes. I am adding the scanner code that sends the data and the api side code that is receiving it in the description.

Comment: SO you are trying to send json data from node API and catch it react end right ?

Comment: yes! That is what I am trying to do

Comment: Inside your node route file send response like  below                 res.status(200).json(modMsg);  this will send reponse in json format. Let me knw if it works or not